# Swagger UI not working behind reverse proxy with prefix path

Tags: spring-boot, reverse-proxy, swagger-ui, application.properties

I'm using Apache reverse proxy for my spring boot application with both the prefix path (set by proxy) and context root in boot application. Hence the url of my application is `https://<host-name>/<prefix-path>/<servlet-context-path>...` Since Swagger in unaware of the proxy there I'm using spring property `server.forward-headers-strategy=framework` which takes care of the `X-Forwarded-Prefix-Path` header. But this property is replacing the context root in the Swagger config url, that is , the url for swagger config becomes `https://<host-name>/<prefix-path/...` which returns a 404. This property does work without the servlet context path. Is there a way so that we can configure swagger to register the correct url?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following configuration in you spring boot config for swagger

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Value("${swagger.host}")
    private String swaggerHost

@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host(swaggerHost)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

where swaggerHost point to your specific application path. You need to specify it in your application.properties file.

```
swagger.host=<host-name>/<prefix-path>/<servlet-context-path>
```

Comment: but since I'm getting the prefix path in the header from proxy ,I want it to be dynamically set not hardcoded